# Problems with context menu of notifyicon when the taskbar is hidden

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

My application has a notifyicon with a context menu. On our clients, the taskbar is set to automatically hide by default. when I try to open the context menu (right click) nothing happens and the taskbar disappears again as soon as I deactivate the automatic hiding in windows, the context menu works without problems. Does anyone know the problem and / or has a solution?

The notifyicon was only added via the visual studio's visual editor, there is currently no logic behind it. Only the context menu has a few buttons.